# A type of object being compared to another in serialization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some classes with Equals and GetHashCode methods overriden. Like this:

```
    // LevelData.cs
    public override bool Equals (object obj)
    {
        return id == ((LevelData)obj).id;
    }
```

When I try to save an object (via serialization), a type of object is compared to another inside a Equals. I dont understand how. This is the erro i get:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
LevelData.Equals (System.Object obj) (at Assets/Scripts/Map/LevelData.cs:50)
System.Collections.Hashtable.KeyEquals (System.Object item, System.Object key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs:679)
System.Collections.Hashtable.Find (System.Object key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs:730)
System.Collections.Hashtable.Contains (System.Object key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs:494)
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationObjectManager.RegisterObject (System.Object obj) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization/SerializationObjectManager.cs:50)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.GetObjectData (System.Object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.TypeMetadata& metadata, System.Object& data) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:389)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteObject (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer, Int64 id, System.Object obj) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:306)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteObjectInstance (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer, System.Object obj, Boolean isValueObject) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:293)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteQueuedObjects (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:271)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteObjectGraph (System.IO.BinaryWriter writer, System.Object obj, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectWriter.cs:256)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:232)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:211)
PlayerProfile.Save () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerProfile.cs:95)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guess, objects of type `LevelData` are compared to the objects of another types during serialization. Try to check the `Type` of the `obj` before casting:

```
public override bool Equals (object obj)
{
    return obj is LevelData ? id == ((LevelData)obj).id : false;
}
```

Comment: yeah but is that correct? I mean, that doesnt happen before. Why now serialization is messing, checking a type that isnt supposed to be checked?

Comment: @Fabricio You're casting an `object` into a `LevelData` without first making sure the cast is possible. Judging by the stack trace, an internal hash table appears to be checking for duplicate data. You might not think that equality check is important, but there is a reason that [recommended practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx) is to simply return false when checking equality for mismatched types.